# Graph traversal with A* algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, traversal, a-star

Hey, I'm AI Student and gonna try my homework that is implementation of A* algorithm in order to traversal a graph. i use c++ codes and what i made for now is below code which is only a Graph class + insertedge and vertices functions.
but now i'm confused of how to define cost function (f= h(n) + g(n)) ...

also any code refrence or explain of how A* works for graphs would help me . what i found in google was about pathfinding via a* and it has nothing with traversal graph.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Graph;
class node {
    friend class Graph;
private:
    char data;
    int cost;
    node *next;
    node *vlist;
    bool goal;
    bool visited;
public:
    node(char d,int c, bool g){
        cost = c;
        goal = g;
        next = NULL;
        data = d;
        vlist = NULL;
        visited = false;
    }
};

class Graph {
private:
    node *Headnodes;
    char n;
public:
    Graph ()
    {
        Headnodes = NULL;
    }
    void InsertVertex(char n, int c, bool g);
    void InsertEdge(char n, char m, int c);
    void PrintVertices();
    void Expand(char n);
};

/////////////////
//  INSERTION  //
/////////////////
void Graph::InsertVertex(char n, int c, bool g){
    node *temp = new node(n,c,g);
    if(Headnodes==NULL)
    {
        Headnodes=temp;
        return;
    }

    node *t=Headnodes;
    while(t->vlist!=NULL)
        t=t->vlist;
    t->vlist=temp;
}

void Graph::InsertEdge(char n, char m, int c){
    int temp_cost = 0;
    if(Headnodes==NULL)
        return;

    node *x=Headnodes;
    while(x!=NULL){
        if(x->data==m)
            temp_cost = (x->cost+c);
        x = x->vlist;
    }
    node *t=Headnodes;
    node *temp=new node(m,temp_cost,false);

    while(t!=NULL){
        if(t->data==n){
            node *s=t;
            while(s->next!=NULL)
                s=s->next;
            s->next=temp;
        }
        t=t->vlist;
    }
}

int min_cost = 1000;
bool enough = false;
void Graph::PrintVertices(){
    node *t=Headnodes;
    while(t!=NULL){
        cout<<t->data<<"\t";
        t=t->vlist;
    }
}

void Graph::Expand(char n){
    cout << n << "\t";
    char temp_min;
    node *t=Headnodes;
    while(t!=NULL){
        if(t->data==n && t->visited == false){
            t->visited = true;
            if (t->goal)
                return;
            while(t->next!=NULL){
                if (t->next->cost <= min_cost){
                    min_cost=t->next->cost;
                    temp_min = t->next->data;
                }
                t = t->next;
            }
        }
        t=t->vlist;
    }
    Expand(temp_min);
}

int main(){
    Graph g;
    g.InsertVertex('A',5,false);
    g.InsertVertex('B',1,false);
    g.InsertVertex('C',9,false);
    g.InsertVertex('D',5,false);
    g.InsertVertex('E',1,false);
    g.InsertVertex('F',3,false);
    g.InsertVertex('G',2,false);
    g.InsertVertex('J',1,false);
    g.InsertVertex('K',0,true);

    g.InsertEdge('A','B',2);
    g.InsertEdge('A','C',1);
    g.InsertEdge('B','A',2);
    g.InsertEdge('B','D',1);
    g.InsertEdge('B','E',1);
    g.InsertEdge('C','A',1);
    g.InsertEdge('C','F',1);
    g.InsertEdge('C','G',1);
    g.InsertEdge('E','J',3);
    g.InsertEdge('E','K',3);

    g.PrintVertices();

    cout<<"\n\n";
    g.Expand('A');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO the only response this deserves is "STFW". Since you mention you did google, the "W" means "Wikipedia". Their articles on Dijkstra and A* are quite comprehensive (no code, but the algorithm descriptions are good). As for obvious omissions in your code above, you don't have any data to base your heuristics (`h(n)`) on, so you can't define it. Also `visited` is not enough, you need to store `f(n)` and you need a queue with tentative distances.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is only a graph search algorithm.

You forgot the essence of the A* algorithm, that is the *h(n)* cost, that comes from an heuristic calculation.

You have to implement a method, the *h(n)* that will calculate, based on yours heuritics, the possible cost from actual path to the final path, and this value will be used to calculate the walking cost:

*f'(n) = g(n) + h'(n)*, being the *g(n)* the already know cost, at your case, the *x->cost*.

> g(n) is the total distance cost it has
> taken to get from the starting
> position to the current location.
>
> h'(n) is the estimated distance cost from
> the current position to the goal
> destination/state. A heuristic
> function is used to create this
> estimate on how far away it will take
> to reach the goal state.
>
> f'(n) is the sum of g(n) and h'(n).
> This is the current estimated shortest
> path. f(n) is the true shortest path
> which is not discovered until the A*
> algorithm is finished.

So, what you have to do:

- Implement a method heuristic_cost(actual_node, final_node);
- Use this value together with the actual cost, like the equation before, by example: min_cost=t->next->cost + heuristic_cost(t->next, final_node) ;

I really like the explanation here: [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171022224528/http://www.policyalmanac.org:80/games/aStarTutorial.htm) , cleaner than wikipedia's explanation.